# Why does set_rules() method in CodeIgniter give error?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So, I am new to CodeIgniter and I decided to follow a tutorial which builds a CMS. I wrote the exactly same thing in my code, but when I click `Submit` button, it gives me this error (My CodeIgniter version is 3.1.6):

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Product::$input

Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

Line Number: 171

Backtrace:

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/codeigniter_cms/panel/application/controllers/Product.php
Line: 40
Function: set_rules

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/codeigniter_cms/panel/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once


An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function method() on null

Filename: /opt/lampp/htdocs/codeigniter_cms/panel/system/libraries/Form_validation.php

Line Number: 171

Backtrace:

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/codeigniter_cms/panel/application/controllers/Product.php
Line: 40
Function: set_rules

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/codeigniter_cms/panel/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Here is my Product controller code:

```
<?php

class Product extends CI_Controller {

public $viewFolder = "";

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->viewFolder = "product_v";
    $this->load->model("product_model");
}
// index method
// new form method

public function save() {
    $this->load->library("form_validation");

    $this->form_validation->set_rules("title", "Title", "required|trim");
    $this->form_validation->set_message(
        array(
            "required" => "{field} field must be filled."
        )
    );

    $validate = $this->form_validation->run();
    if ($validate) {
        echo "Saved";
    } else {
        echo validation_errors();
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h4 class="m-b-lg">
        Add New Product
    </h4>
</div><!-- END column -->
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-body">
            <form action="<?php echo base_url("product/save"); ?>" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <input name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <textarea name="description" class="m-0" data-plugin="summernote" data-options="{height: 250}"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-outline">Submit</button>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url("product/index"); ?>" class="btn btn-md btn-danger btn-outline">Cancel</a>
            </form>
        </div><!-- .widget-body -->
</div><!-- END column -->
```

I'm trying to fix this error for hours. Any help would appreciated.

Comment: use this `$this->form_validation->set_message('title', 'title must be filled..');`

Comment: @KUMAR Thanks for your comment but it is not about `set_message()`. It gives error about `set_rules()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the problem.

The problem was not in `CodeIgniter`, but in `LAMPP`. So, I removed `LAMPP` and made a fresh install, and my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Form_validation library doesn't load where you placed it. I'll suggest you place it in your class construct or just autoload it in your `config/autoload.php` file.

- In your class construct

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    // Add your other models, helpers, etc here
}
```

OR

- Autoload it globally in your `application/config/autoload.php` file

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading form helper

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Documentation doesn't says to use form validation library with the form helper. But I think it is required. I got the same problem long time ago. But I forgot the solution. I hope this should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is already activated.